# Processing: Creating shapes that change size through draw loops

Tags: processing

I am trying to create a visualization where the nodes of my network change size in a loop as the visualization progresses (I have stripped out the interactions between the nodes for simplicity here). I have the array `sizes` that is looped over in the `draw` function with index `j`. I am not sure why the nodes are not changing size. Any insight into this problem would be appreciated.

```
int numBalls = 5;

Ball[] balls = new Ball[numBalls];

float[] sizes = {15,25,35,45,55,65};

void setup() {
  size(800, 400);
  int l = 0 ;
  for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball(random(width),random(height), random(30, 50), i, balls);
  }
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 204);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    print("\nNEW ID\n");
    print(i);
    print("\n");
    print("Diameter in balls\n");
    print(balls[i].diameter);
    print("\n");
    balls[i].diameter = sizes[j];
    print("Diameter in balls after fix\n");
    print(balls[i].diameter);
    balls[i].display();  
    }
  }
}

class Ball {
  float x, y;
  float diameter;
  float mass; 
  float vx = 0;
  float vy = 0;
  int id;
  Ball[] others;

  Ball(float xin, float yin, float din, int idin, Ball[] oin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    diameter = din;
    mass = 50;
    id = idin;
    others = oin;
  } 

  void display() {
    textSize(32);
    fill(0,255,0,255);
    print("\nDiameter in display\n");
    print(diameter);
    print("\n");
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    print("\nDiameter in display\n");
    print(diameter);
    print("\n");
    fill(255, 0, 0, 255);
    text(id,x,y);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help to know what language you are working with here. I am assuming Java??

Comment: @winterblood It's Processing programming language as mentioned in tag.

Comment: @Majlik Ahh, thanks. Never heard of it, so I figured it was just a generic tag since the code looks like far too many other C-like languages.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, in your draw() function you are running over the array of sizes with the first for-loop and assigning the value of that size to the balls. This way in each draw() you subsequently attach each size on each ball, and every time the size you attach overwrites the previous one... Remember, the window of Processing only refreshes after the draw() has finished! Instead of looping over all the sizes in each draw() you probably want a different size in each draw(). So a way to do that would be:

```
int numBalls = 5;
int sizeCounter = 0;
int everySoManyFramesChange = 3;

Ball[] balls = new Ball[numBalls];
float[] sizes = {
  15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65
};

void setup() {
  size(800, 400);
  int l = 0 ;
  for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball(random(width), random(height), random(30, 50), i, balls);
  }
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 204);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    balls[i].diameter = sizes[sizeCounter];
    balls[i].display();
  }
  if (frameCount%everySoManyFramesChange == 0) sizeCounter=(sizeCounter+1)%sizes.length;
}
class Ball {
  float x, y;
  float diameter;
  float mass; 
  float vx = 0;
  float vy = 0;
  int id;
  Ball[] others;

  Ball(float xin, float yin, float din, int idin, Ball[] oin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    diameter = din;
    mass = 50;
    id = idin;
    others = oin;
  } 

  void display() {
    textSize(32);
    fill(0, 255, 0, 255);
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    fill(255, 0, 0, 255);
    text(id, x, y);
  }
}
```

By the way I removed all those print statements because they are making the sketch horribly slow, but be my guest and re-introduce them!